# Storing Output in table in GUI Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new in GUI Matlab. I want to have a table of values in GUI, which get results from m.file. The table is of 9x10. (9 parameters, each will get 10 results). In m.file, I have a loop of getting the results of these 9 parameters and this loop iterates 10 time. I want to save the result 9 parameter per iteration of loop in a row of this table. How I can proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing a table's data is as easy as: `set(hTable, 'Data', data)`. What exactly are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You can save them into a `9x10` matrix and loop writing parameters into it. Like this:

```
res = zeros(9, 10);

for i=1:9
    for j=1:10
        res(i, j) = ...
    end
end
```

Comment: I am afraid, its seems difficult get the parameters results in a matrix form, as the parameters are obtained at different stages. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user3275911 What do you mean by *different stages*?